# When i clicking second time on OnClick( SetState) i got a mistake, what should i do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i clicking on <a onClick{() => "function"}> first time it works everything changing fine, but when i clicking second time everything breaks.
here i got code :

```
function ref(sub) {
    console.log(Subjects)
    SetSubjects(Subjects[sub] = true)
    console.log(Subjects)
};

const [Subjects, SetSubjects] = useState({
    "Mathematics": false,
    "Physics": false,
    "Ukranian": false,
    "English": false,
    "Chemistry": false,
    "Informatics": false,
    "History": false
})
return (
        <div className="area">
            <div className="logo_header"><a className="logo_header_text" href="/">Owly</a></div>
            <h1 className="tittle">Choose the Subject</h1>
            <div className="select_btns">
                <a onClick={() => ref("Mathematics")} >Mathematics</a>
                <a onClick={() => ref("Physics")} >Physics</a>
                <a onClick={() => ref("Ukranian")} >Ukranian</a>
                <a onClick={() => ref("English")} >English</a>
                <a onClick={() => ref("Chemistry")}>Chemistry</a>
                <a onClick={() => ref("Informatics")}>Informatics</a>
                <a onClick={() => ref("History")}>History</a>
            </div>
```

here i got screens
First click:
[image: first click]

Second click:
[image]

and it doesn't matter which button i choose

Comment: You Don't have any buttons in your code, only links. And links should have an href- and not an onclick-Attribute. Use a `<button>` for a button. But only if it is a button and not a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
SetSubjects(Subjects[sub] = true)
```

The *result* of the expression `Subjects[sub] = true` is the value `true`, so you're setting `Subjects` to the value `true`.  Which of course doesn't have any of the properties you're expecting from your `Subjects` object.

I suspect you're looking for this:

```
SetSubjects({ ...Subjects, [sub]: true })
```

This will set `Subjects` to an object containing all of the properties currently on `Subjects`, as well as set the property defined by the value in `sub` to be `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear